# Passing MYSQL echod image ID through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Could someone point me in the right direction for a tutorial, I've been looking for ajax tutorials that pass MySQL query answers through to another url.

What I'm trying to produce is a database that lists EP information, track title, artist name that sort of thing. But the important thing is the EP artwork which I have stored as a VARCHAR url within the database as "picture_url".

I want the pictures all to print into one `<div>` so that once they are clicked the EP information as well as a larger image is loaded into the `<div id= "epinfo">`

What I've done is set the images ID to the databases auto incremented `releases_id`. This way I can make my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM releases WHERE releases_id = //image id
```

I have tried turning this into a variable to send through ajax but I can not seem to place the variable, if it's before the `$j` it won't work as `$j` is part of the variable. To place it after interrupts the echo function. Am I right in saying that `$j` is not a global variable? If so could this be the problem as I have tried to change this but failed?

Is their a tutorial that is a little more specific in this kind of ajax request?

I'm new to PHP and Ajax programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my php code:

```
<div id="epcovers">
<?php
require_once 'arcko_admin.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if(!$db_server) die("unable to connect to mysql:" . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM releases";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " .mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    echo '<img src="' . mysql_result($result,$j,'picture_url') . '" class= "ep" id= "' .     mysql_result($result,$j,'release_id'). ' " width= "200" height= "200"/>';
}

mysql_close($db_server);

?>
    <div id="epinfo">
 <?php
echo //track title, artist information, etc.


?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see any ajax calls in this code...or is this your php backend? also you may consider using MySQLi or PDO for your database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysql_result()`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM releases";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: " .mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '<img src="' . $row['picture_url'] . '" class="ep" id="' . $rom['release_id'] . '" width= "200" height= "200"/>';
}

mysql_close($db_server);
```

### Important

**Since you are beginning with PHP please read:
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**

Comment: Thanks guys, new to the languages and only just seen the compelling arguments to change my code. I'll have to look into re writing the code but in the mean time that's great help with the `MySQL_fetch_assoc($result)`. Is their ajax tutorials that help send the `$row['releases_id']` through?